# PowerShell: Change to module shows no effect - some kind of recompile needed?

Tags: powershell, module, dsc

I am currently in the process of setting up a DSC pull server using the DSC resource kit wave 8.

Unfortunatelly the module `MSFT_xDSCWebService.psm1` has a bug and throws an exception when ever another locale then 'en' is in use.

The exception message tells me it's looking for a file called `resource.dll` in the wrong place. I have therefor made changes to the module, so it looks in the right place.

However the changes show no effect, even a `Write-Host "Test...` is not showing up in the output. Is there somekind of cache that needs a refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your Local Configuration Manager (LCM) settings, you set `AllowModuleOverwrite` to `$true`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because DSC has already loaded the previous version of the module - which is in memory. An easy way to refresh is to bring down the DSC process and run the configuration again (*do not try this on a production system as other WMI providers are co-hosted with DSC*)

gps wmiprvse | ?{$_.modules.ModuleName -ieq 'dsccore.dll'} | kill -Force